# Menu Button from AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

My PDF viewer is Skim.app, and I use the below bit of applescript code to ask it to re-read all of its open documents from disk, which I need to have it do very often. The trouble is that Skim.app is a bit buggy, in more ways than one. One of its bugs is that when it re-loads an existing document it garbles it a bit. Fortunately zooming once and un-zooming once fixes the garbling, but it's very annoying to have to do manually.

The zoom button is in the menu item "PDF" -> "Zoom In", and the unzoom is "PDF" -> "Zoom Out." It is possible to have the applescript code do a zoom and unzoom for me every time it runs? If so how?

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript << EOF
  set theFile to POSIX file "$1" as alias
  set thePath to POSIX path of theFile
  tell application "Skim"
    activate
    set theDocs to get documents whose path is thePath
    try
      if (count of theDocs) > 0 then revert theDocs
    end try
    open theFile
  end tell
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use System Events to click menu items. Also you can pass arguments by adding an explicit run handler.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv
    tell application "Skim"
        activate
        revert (documents where path is item 1 of argv)
        open POSIX file (item 1 of argv) as alias
    end tell
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Skim"
        click menu item "Zoom In" of menu 1 of menu bar item "PDF" of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Zoom Out" of menu 1 of menu bar item "PDF" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end run
```